# Proxyserver as Home button

Tags: stock-android

I am using Nexus 5 and recently did factory reset. Now I have Proxyserver as Home button in Android settings along with Google launcher and because of that I am able to see annoying Google ads on screen. Have any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That should be a malware or something related. Try disabling it in Apps or root your phone and uninstall it. Hope it helps.